# Handling JSON in android

Tags: android

Hi am new to JSON and I will like to retrieve the values for the json below

```
{"error":"0","uid":"160","langId":"2","rank":"1"}
```

I wrote a JSONParser class, but the main activity class has got me stuck. Below is the code

```
private static final String LOGTAG = "MyActivity";
    private static String JSONurl = "http://www.afroklore.org/mobile/boot.php?actn=post_prov&lang=1&uid=2&prov=";
    private static final String ERROR = "error";
    private static final String UID = "uid";
    private static final String LANGID = "langId";
    private static final String RANK = "rank";
    JSONArray output = null;
    String id, error, langId, rank;

if (MenuActivity.status == 2) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONurl);

            try {
                output = json.getJSONArray(ERROR);

                for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = output.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    id = c.getString(UID);
                    error = c.getString(ERROR);
                    langId = c.getString(LANGID);
                    rank = c.getString(RANK);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    /*
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(ERROR, error);
                    map.put(UID, id);
                    map.put(LANGID, langId);
                    map.put(RANK, rank);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    outputField.add(map);*/
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return result;

protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String msg = "Login successful";

            if (MenuActivity.status == 2) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, result);
                // Log.d(LOGTAG, outputField.get(ERROR));
                Log.d(LOGTAG, error + " " + id + " " + langId + " " + rank);
```

}

Comment: And what is exactly the problem?..is there an error?

Comment: "I wrote a JSONParser" Why? Android has one already: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: is this complete json or one element of array?

Comment: You may find this link helpful: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your json webservice respose [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).it's containing only one json object as string provided by you

```
{"error":"0","uid":"160","langId":"2","rank":"1"}
```

so parse it as

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONurl);
     try {
         // Storing each json item in variable
         id = json.getString(UID);
         error = json.getString(ERROR);
         langId = json.getString(LANGID);
         rank = json.getString(RANK);
           //..your code here
```

Comment: Hi,it still returned null values

Comment: @nnanna : this is http://www.afroklore.org/mobile/boot.php?actn=post_prov&lang=1&uid=2&prov= complete url where you are making post request?

Comment: because when i'm trying to check this url in browser then webservice only returning {"error":"1","error_msg":"Empty data posted"} data

Comment: {"error":"1","error_msg":"Empty data posted"} implies invalid username or password
You would need to be signed up to get the response as written by me

Comment: @nnanna : use Log.d(LOGTAG, error + " " + id + " " + langId + " " + rank); in doInBackground and check you are getting data or not

Answer (score 1):

you can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for parsing the JSON strings

In your case create a class that represents the JSON parameters as below

```
public class Header {
///{"error":"0","uid":"160","langId":"2","rank":"1"}

    private String error;
    private String uid;
    private String langId;
    private String rank;
    /**
     * Gets the error.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the error.</tt>
     */
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the error.
     *
     * @param error <tt> the error to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the uid.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the uid.</tt>
     */
    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the uid.
     *
     * @param uid <tt> the uid to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the langId.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the langId.</tt>
     */
    public String getLangId() {
        return langId;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the langId.
     *
     * @param langId <tt> the langId to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setLangId(String langId) {
        this.langId = langId;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the rank.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the rank.</tt>
     */
    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the rank.
     *
     * @param rank <tt> the rank to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Header [error=" + error + ", uid=" + uid + ", langId=" + langId
                + ", rank=" + rank + "]";
    }




}
```

Now parse the required JSON string in just two lines

```
String jSonData = "{\"error\":\"0\",\"uid\":\"160\",\"langId\":\"2\",\"rank\":\"1\"}";
Header header = new Gson().fromJson(jSonData, Header.class);
System.out.println("Header : "+header);
```

You would need gson jar binary for this code to run.

- Download [GSON JAR](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/files/google-gson-2.2.1-release.zip)
- create a resource folder named 'libs' in your project folder
- copy the gson jar to this folder and add to build path
- now you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

`{ , }` is represent `JSONobject` and `[ ,]` is represent `JSONArray`

```
{"error":"0","uid":"160","langId":"2","rank":"1"}
```

You can not take for loop for the `JSONobject` ,It use for the `JSONArray`.

You can check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10594036/1263679),

Here question is difference but use the JSON in that solution.

For more understanding check this [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).
 I hope it help you.